# UK Higher Education Academic Teaching Qualification

Tags: application, teaching, faculty-application, united-kingdom

I have come across a few questions similar to the following during academic job application process at UK HEIs. I think I understand and I am aware of the choices from 2 to 10. However, option 1 confuses me, I'll be more specific below.

> Please indicate if you have successfully completed a higher education
>   teaching qualification or any other relevant teaching qualification
>
> 1. Successfully completed an institutional provision in teaching in the higher education sector accredited against the UK Professional
>      Standards Framework
> 2. Recognised by the HEA as an Associate Fellow
> 3. Recognised by the HEA as a Fellow
> 4. Recognised by the HEA as a Senior Fellow
> 5. Recognised by the HEA as a Principal Fellow
> 6. Holder of a National Teaching Fellowship Scheme Individual Award
> 7. Holder of a PGCE in secondary education, further education, lifelong learning or any other equivalent qualification
> 8. Accredited as a teacher of their subject by a professional body
> 9. Other accreditation or qualification in teaching in the higher education sector
> 10. Overseas accreditation or qualification for any level of teaching

When I was a PhD student at a UK university, I completed a one-day workshop on “Survival Skills in Teaching” which was required before I could be TA. So, does this training satisfy option 1? In addition, I have attended two to three days faculty development trainings overseas (outside UK). Do these trainings allow me to pick any of the choices?

I will much appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is for training courses run by universities (mostly in the past, before most of them became HEA accredited) that are roughly equivalent to options 2 or 3, but that were not officially accredited by HEA. Their demands and standards used to differ wildly, but I am afraid none of them were a one day workshop on "survival skills".

Comment: Note that some UK Unis (including my Russell Group one) have left the HEA, citing rising costs that don't line up with the value. We're back to our own accreditation via training course that is HEA equivalent. To answer the poster, no: this is the equivalent of something like 40 credits at a postgrad level. They even give staff student cards for the duration of it.